# What's the simplest way to make a combination local and remote file open and save in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express

I am writing an app that can load/save files from the local drive as well as from the remote server. I have it working with distinct dialogs for each location (local,remote) and actions (open/save) I would like to combine it into 2 dialogs each of which allows user to choose location.

I can't seem to find anyone who's done this. Before I go through the work of coding it myself I though I would ask if anyone had suggestions.

I am using React/Typescript on the front end and Express on the back end.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

-Flex

Comment: What's the problem?